# Is the movie in Skinner's Sense of Snow based off a real film?

Tags: the-simpsons

In the Simpsons episode, [Skinner's Sense of Snow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinner%27s_Sense_of_Snow) there is an imaginary film called, "The Christmas That Almost Wasn't, But Then Was". The movie was set in Santa's workshop, and featured Christmas hobgoblins and Little Bo Peep.

[image: black and white cartoon with three kids in identical clothes]

Is this a parody of a real movie? I saw there was a film called [The Christmas that Almost Wasn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Christmas_That_Almost_Wasn%27t), although the plot seemed entirely different.

Comment: Is it Smilla's Sense of Snow by any chance?

Comment: @JoelSpolsky: That's just the title of the episode.  [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinner's_Sense_of_Snow#Cultural_references), there's no other references to Smilla's besides the title.  He's talking about a short film as one of the scenes in the episode.

Comment: "The Christmas That Almost Wasn't, But Then Was" is an apt description of pretty much _every_ Christmas-centric movie plot. Almost always, the stakes are that Christmas might be cancelled this year due to plot events, but then it gets saved in the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to mainstay Simpsons fansite, [The Simpsons Archive](http://www.simpsonsarchive.com/episodes/CABF06.txt), the film bears similarities to Laurel and Hardy's *[March of the Wooden Soldiers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0024852/)*:

> The film that Skinner shows the class is
>      similar to the Laurel and Hardy film, the March of the Wooden Soldiers.
>      Based on the tale Babes in Toyland, the film features the duo as Stanley
>      Dumb and Ollie Dee, two residents of Mother Goose Land.  There, they help
>      Tom-Tom, the Pipers son and Little Bo Peep to fall in love while, with the
>      help of giant wooden soldiers, saving the town from Barnaby, the Crooked
>      Man, and the Bogie Men, man-beast creatures that the hobgoblins in the
>      school film resemble.